# django abstract model inheritance import

Tags: python, django, inheritance, model, abstract

I wonder how i can import an abstract model into another app

world_elements holds:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    """
    Holds x,y coordinates of a virtual 2d map. 
    """

    x = models.IntegerField()
    y = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s, %s" % (self.x, self.y)
```

now in another app i try:

```
from world_elements.models import Location

class NpcTown(Location):
    """
    A town with their coordinates trianinggrounds quest office and all other relevant attributes
    """

    # general town information
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 63)
    flavor = models.TextField(max_length = 511)
    guild = models.ForeignKey(NpcGuild)

    # locations
    trainingground = models.ForeignKey(TrainingGround, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

but now i get ImportError: cannot import name Location

How do i import an abstract model?

Comment: Why would you import from `world_elements.models` if the model is in `world_elements`?

Comment: please post your project file structure

Comment: Sorry if it was unclear,  my other model is in characters app,  or in the wons app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplifying the names of the classes a bit, the following works for me
in Django 1.7, which is the latest stable release at the time of this
writing.

**Directory layout**

```
    project
          \_ apps
              \_ __init__.py
              \_ A
              \_ B
          \_ config
              \_ __init__.py
              \_ settings.py
              \_ urls.py
              \_ wsgi.py
          \_ data
          \_ makefile
          \_ manage.py
          \_ README.md
```

In the above, app `A` contains the abstract model.  `B` uses it, as
follows:

**Abstract Class(es)**

```
class AModel(Model):
    ...
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Then

**Concrete Class(es)**

```
from apps.A.models import AModel

class BModel(AModel):
    ...
    blah = "ayyo"
```

Note that apps, A, and B all must contain an `__init__.py` file.

Don't be afraid to break free of the Django directory layout conventions
imposed by `manage.py start{app,project}`.  Doing so will free your mind
and you will love having things neatly organized.

Another thing that helps debugging module imports is simply `print`ing
the module imported.  Then you can tell what is actually being resolved.
For example:

```
from apps.A.models import AModel
print AModel # <class 'apps.A.models.AModel'>
```

And:

```
import apps
print apps # <module 'apps' from '/home/g33k/gits/checkouts/my/project/apps/__init__.pyc'>
```

Comment: Dude, you made my day. I have struggled with this import problem for quite some time. and yes, i should have just remade my folder structure. This question is very old and i actually already forgot it.. So far i found a workaround (which i hate) to solve this problem.  Dude you the man

Comment: small update maybe for you. also add the __init__.py file as well to the settings map

Comment: No problem :)  Yes, I added the `__init__.py` to the settings directory - it was there in my setup, I just forgot to include it.

Comment: just encountered another import error:(   from apps.heroes.models import Hero. now im sure the class exists but when i try to syncdb, i get File "/home/ikke/panda/Buah/apps/heroes/models.py", line 4, in <module>  (one model imports town from heroes, the other hero from towns. . )
    from apps.towns.models import Town
  File "/home/ikke/panda/Buah/apps/towns/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from apps.heroes.models import Hero
am i having a circular import again?

Comment: now i think i could solve this by using import apps.heroes.models as app_heroes and then use app_heroes.Hero but than it cant find my models file (i got an __init__ in the apps map and also in de app maps themselve)

Comment: Please edit your question above to include the source code where you are having the error.

Answer (score -1):

In a normal structure like this:

```
my_project
  - /my_project
    - /settings.py
  - /app1
    - /models.py
      * class Model1...
  - /app2
    - /models.py
      * class Model2...
```

From app1/models.py this worked for me:

```
from django.db import models
from my_project.app1.models import Model1

class Model2(Model1):
    ...
```

Using Django 11.1

Answer (score -3):

Try

```
from world_elements import Location
```

Comment: Then i get the next error: ImportError: cannot import name Location